# UN condemns Rohingya human rights abuses 134-9 with 28 abstentions. Which countries voted against?

Tags: united-nations, myanmar

On 2019-12-27, the UN General Assembly approved a resolution strongly condemning human rights abuses against [Myanmar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myanmar)'s [Rohingya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rohingya_people),
 134-9 with 28 abstentions.

I can't find which countries opposed or abstained in online news articles or on the UN website.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The voting record for the resolution is as follows:

[image: the list of who voted what way]

The countries voting against are **Belarus, Cambodia, China, Lao People’s Democratic Republic, Myanmar, Philippines, Russian Federation, Vietnam, and Zimbabwe**.

The text of the resolution can be found [here](https://undocs.org/en/A/74/399/Add.3).

Comment: Why do some of them (e.g. Cuba) not have a symbol next to them? What does that mean?

Comment: @Stormblessed They possibly didn't attend the UN GA session, so they didn't vote.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation about why some countries might have voted the way they did has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102681/discussion-on-answer-by-panda-un-condemns-rohingya-human-rights-abuses-134-9-wit).

Comment: Doesn’t Russia have veto power so this didn’t pass?

Comment: @OldBunny2800 This vote was in the General Assembly. Veto applies only in the Security Council.

Answer (score 23):

***Countries Voted in favor, against or abstained.***

**In favour:**

> Afghanistan, Albania, Algeria, Andorra, Angola, Antigua and Barbuda, Argentina,
>   Armenia, Australia, Austria, Azerbaijan, Bahamas, Bahrain, Bangladesh, Barbados,
>   Belgium, Belize, Benin, Bosnia and Herzegovina, Botswana, Brazil, Brunei Darussalam, 
>   Bulgaria, Burkina Faso, Cabo Verde, Canada, Chad, Chile, Colombia, Comoros, Congo,
>   Costa Rica, Côte d’Ivoire, Croatia, Cyprus, Czechia, Denmark, Djibouti, Dominican 
>    Republic, Ecuador, Egypt, El Salvador, Estonia, Ethiopia, Finland, France, Gabon, 
>   Gambia, Georgia, Germany, Ghana, Greece, Guatemala, Guyana, Haiti, Honduras, Hungary, 
>   Iceland, Indonesia, Iran (Islamic   Republic of), Iraq, Ireland, Israel, Italy, 
>   Jamaica, Jordan, Kazakhstan, Kiribati, Kuwait, Kyrgyzstan, Latvia, Lebanon, Liberia, 
>   Libya, Liechtenstein, Lithuania, Luxembourg, Madagascar, Malawi, Malaysia, 
>   Maldives, Mali, Malta, Marshall Islands, Mauritania, Mauritius, Mexico, Micronesia 
>   (Federated States of), Monaco, Montenegro, Morocco, Netherlands, New Zealand, Niger, 
>   Nigeria, North Macedonia, Norway, Oman, Pakistan, Panama, Paraguay, Peru, Poland,
>   Portugal, Qatar, Republic of Korea, Republic of Moldova, Romania, Rwanda, Saint 
>   Kitts and Nevis, Saint Lucia, Samoa, San Marino, Saudi Arabia, Senegal, Seychelles, 
>   Sierra Leone, Slovakia, Slovenia, Solomon Islands, Somalia, South Africa, Spain, 
>   Sudan, Suriname, Sweden, Switzerland, Tajikistan, Togo, Tunisia, Turkey, Tuvalu, 
>   Uganda, United Arab Emirates, United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland, 
>   United Republic of Tanzania, United States of America, Uruguay, Vanuatu, Yemen.

**Against:**

> Belarus, Cambodia, China, Lao People’s Democratic Republic, Myanmar,
>   Philippines, Russian Federation, Viet Nam, Zimbabwe.

**Abstaining:**

> Bhutan, Bolivia (Plurinational State of), Burundi, Cameroon, Democratic
>   People’s Republic of Korea, Dominica, Equatorial Guinea, Eritrea, Fiji,
>   Grenada, Guinea-Bissau, India, Japan, Kenya, Lesotho, Mongolia,
>   Mozambique, Namibia, Nauru, Nepal, Palau, Papua New Guinea, Saint Vincent
>   and the Grenadines, Serbia, Singapore, Sri Lanka, Thailand, Timor-Leste,
>   Tonga, Trinidad and Tobago, Venezuela (Bolivarian Republic of), Zambia.

[The data has been taken from this source page 5-6](https://undocs.org/en/A/74/399/Add.3)

Comment: Thanks @AbdulMuheet. Is that the most electronic-friendly format the UN publish listing votes?